Access music on Mac mini from a TV
I have a Mac mini running 24 hours a day.  It is full of music.
I also have two smart televisions in the house (a Samsung and a JVC Fire TV).
I would like to be able to browse my music library from a TV, using a native TV interface (ie not have to switch to a different input, or use a different remote).
How do I do this?
PS I do not have an Apple Music subscription, and I don't really want to pay to access music I already own.

This might be better asked of technical support for the TV's or any discussion boards about the TVs. If the TV's support Apple Airplay you might be able to play music from the Mac Mini to the TV's. but that means using the Mini to push the music to the TV rather than using the TV to access the Mini.

For this site scope, the answer is pop an Apple TV on each and use home sharing. Is that something you would consider an answer? It would be easier to have them ini push a music scream using AirPlay and inexpensive Bluetooth receivers sending audio only to the tv, but that gets you no video and no “browse”

Could look into using something like plex to host your media on the mac and access it from the tv using the dedicated plex app, they do have a premium subscription but wouldn't be required for this setup.
